# Removing specific times and days every week from time dataframe

Tags: r, time, posixct

Been learning R for a couple months and stumbled across an issue that I can't seem to find yet on stackoverflow. I have a timeframe dataset dictated by:

```
ts <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt("2014-08-01 15:00"), as.POSIXlt("2017-08-04 19:33"), by="min")
ts <- format.POSIXct(ts,'%Y%m%d %H%M')
df <- data.frame(timestamp=ts)
```

I have seen how to remove specific times from every day, and how to remove complete days such as weekends/holidays but I am looking to remove subsets from every week, specifically 8:00 on every Saturday to 9:00 on every Monday throughout the entire dataset. I have tried doing the reverse, by subsetting the period I need by using lubridate (thanks @Christian):

```
dfc = ymd_hm(df$timestamp)
df[day(dfc) == 2 & hour(dfc) >= 9 | day(dfc) == 7 & hour(dfc) >= 8,]
```

but it didn't seem to work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant subset when using lubridate with square brackets. Instead its called like a regular function. try to replace e.g. hour[dfc] with hour(dfc) and you should be fine.

edit: to subset a range you need to be aware of == is not like >=

edit2: a bit more of a pointing into the right direction

```
ts_sat_until_monday = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt("2014-08-02 09:00"), 
as.POSIXlt("2014-08-04 08:00"), by = 1)

unique(day(ts_sat_until_monday))
unique(hour(ts_sat_until_monday))
#what about sunday? up to you
```

Comment: Did you check the base setting for lubridate days (sunday == 1 or monday == 1)?

Comment: hey christian, sorry for the prev hasty response. took some time adjusting as I realised what you meant with == not being >= and also looking at base settings for lubridate and found out sunday is indeed 1 thanks. I've then changed the code to

`df[day(dfc) == 2 & hour(dfc) >= 9 | day(dfc) == 7 & hour(dfc) >= 8,]`

but still can't seem to get it work..

Comment: @KevinChen see my 2nd edit. You forgot about sunday and actually it`s not clear to me if you try to keep the range between saturday and monday or not (using ! or not)

Comment: Thanks @Christian - got it. Cheers for being patient :)